# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'cloud_firestore' not found

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run my flutter project on ios simulator and getting the following error:

```
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'cloud_firestore' not found
```

For some reason when I run this on my device with `flutter run --profile` everything works fine. However I want to run using the simulator. This is what I have tried so far:

1. cd ios/pod deintegrate
2. delete pod folder and delete podfile.lock file
3. flutter pub upgrade
4. pod repo update
5. pod install

None of this has worked so far. I've even tried deleting the whole ios folder and reinstalling. Nothing works. This what my pod file looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.1'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      # Force CocoaPods targets to always build for x86_64
      config.build_settings['ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'x86_64'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so after a week of pulling my hair out I figured out what was going on. This problem was due to me updating xcode. I found out what I needed to do is open the xcworkspace file in xcode and add arm64to the excluded architectures [image: add arm64 to each section]

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me, are there any other changes you made that could have helped contribute to solving this issue?